# I'm new to javqascript and html, how can I have a text box in html that tells the answer to js to make it into a variable

Tags: javascript, html

I make a text box in html, and I want to transfer the answer into a javascript so that it makes a variable and that variable being the text in the text box

Comment: Note: You've tagged this question "Java", but JavaScript is a completely different programming language, despite both having "Java" in the name.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an ID of "textInput" attached to your HTML input element, then you can do something like this:

```
const val = document.getElementById("textInput").value;
```

Comment: How would I get an ID?

Comment: Like this: ```<input id="textInput">```